# Merge Replication from SQLServer 2012 to Sql Compact 3.5 SP2

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

Can you please provide me steps to set up Merge Replication from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Compact 3.5 SP2.
I have installed CU7 package and X86 and X64 version of SQL compact 3.5..
I have successfully set up the publisher and the link http://[servername]/Sync/sqlcesa35.dll works with "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Server Agent".

But when I'm trying to set up a subscriber to synchorize, I'm getting an error, "serve agent could not connect to the publiser"